# Calling a function in an object literal in JS...easy

Tags: javascript

Need some help with this very simple JS program to try to apply to get more info for a programming course. It is described as:

First declare an array named myArray. Populate myArray with two strings: your name and a Skype handle. Declare a function as cutName, that takes a string as an argument. cutName should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words like "Joe Smith" would be ["Joe", "Smith"].
Make a new object literal named myData.
Add three key value pairs to myData, by following these guideline:
      fullName: call cutName on the name string stored in myArray
      Skype: refer to your skype handle in myArray
      github:if you have a github handle, enter it as a string, if not enter as null

My lame attempt:

```
var myArray = ["Joe Smith", "joe smith"];
var cutName = function (myArray) {
return myArray.split (" ");
};
var myData = {
  fullName: cutName.myArray[0,1],
  skype: myArray [1],
  github: null
};
```

I am stuck on calling the function cutName on the string stored in myArray. A million thanks in advance!

Comment: I just have to ask, how do you `split()` an array? Oh, now I see, good move on naming the argument the same as the array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myArray = ["Joe Smith", "joe smith"];
var cutName = function (str) {
    return str.split (" ");
};
var myData = {
  fullName: cutName(myArray[0]),   // Pass first element of array (string)
  skype: myArray.length > 1 ? myArray[1] : null,   // Pass second element if present
  github: null
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try `fullName: cutName(myArray[0])`

That way you are calling your `cutName` function and passing it `myArray[0]` which is equal to `"Joe Smith"`.

For clarity rename the parameter `myArray` to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to *call* the `cutName` function: Use parenthesis

  ```
  cutName(…)
  ```

  This will return the array produced by calling the `split` method.
- The name to be cutted is the first item in the array. Use `[0]` [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to access it:

  ```
  cutName(myArray[0])
  ```